# Ant / External libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

When I'm using external libraries (`lucene`) and running my java application through eclipse (run application) all works fine with the libs in the classpath.
But when I'm using Ant, i got this error here:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.store.Directory

I guess this error shows up, cause of an incorrect classpath. Stange that no compilation error occurs, when ant compiles the code. This is my ant file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build">
    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="GUI_P/lucene-6.2.0/lucene-6.2.0/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="GUI_P/lucene-6.2.0/lucene-6.2.0/core/lucene-core-6.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="GUI_P/lucene-6.2.0/lucene-6.2.0/grouping/lucene-grouping-6.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="GUI_P/lucene-6.2.0/lucene-6.2.0/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-6.2.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="GUI_P/lucene-6.2.0/lucene-6.2.0/queries/lucene-queries-6.2.0.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target depends="init" name="build">
        <javac debug="true" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="true">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>    
    <target name="jar" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="GUI_P"/>
        <jar destfile="GUI_P/GUI_P.jar" basedir="bin">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="gui.Gui"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="copySamples" depends="jar">  
        <copy todir="GUI_P/samples">
          <fileset dir="src/gui/samples"/>
         </copy>
    </target>   
</project>
```

Can you please help me here out?

Comment: what is `GUI_P` ? Does not appear to be a valid path on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that strange, because `ClassNotFoundException` arises always when trying a *dynamic instantiation* (through `Class.forName()`). So it is possible that the same classpath produces a right compilation, but it is not complete for an execution: It lacks the **dynamic dependencies**.

In your case, you must add to the execution classpath the **lucene-core** library (at least).